# Decrease vertical space after header in cvlist of currvita

Tags: spacing, itemize, currvita

I want to decrease the vertical space between the header of my cvlist and the first item. 
So "Schulbildung" and the item "Heintz Grundschule Berlin" should be closer than right now. How can I achieve this? Just
\vspace{-1cm} didnt work.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{currvita}

\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{Lebenslauf Heintz Heintz}
  \begin{cvlist}{Schulbildung}
    \item[08/1991--07/2001] Heintz Grundschule Berlin
    \item[08/2001--06/2008] Heintz Schule Berlin \\
     \textit{Abschluss: Abitur (Durchschnittsnote: 2,0)} \\
     \textit{Leistungskurse: Mathematik, Englisch}    
  \end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

I have this:
[image]

and i want this:[image]

smaller space between the two items (perhaps equal to the space after "Schulbildung") would be okay, too.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please add a small graphic, which shows, what you want to achieve. MS-Paint does the job.

Comment: Did you consider the moderncv-package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I patched the `cvlist` environment to change the gap between the header and the list by a user specified value of `\Vshft`, shown here as a very exaggerated -10pt.  Works for both negative and positive `\Vshft` values.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\def\Vshft{-10pt}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{{\cvlistheadingfont#1}}{{\raisebox{\Vshft}{\cvlistheadingfont#1}}%
  \dp\@cvlistheading=\dimexpr\dp\@cvlistheading+\dimexpr\Vshft\relax}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{Lebenslauf Heintz Heintz}
  \begin{cvlist}{Schulbildung}
    \item[08/1991--07/2001] Heintz Grundschule Berlin
    \item[08/2001--06/2008] Heintz Schule Berlin \\
     \textit{Abschluss: Abitur (Durchschnittsnote: 2,0)} \\
     \textit{Leistungskurse: Mathematik, Englisch}    
  \end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That distance is hard coded in the definition of `cvlist` environment like

```
        \parbox[b]{0pt}{%
          \makebox[0pt][l]{\box\@cvlistheading}%
          \\*[0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt]%   <---------- this line
```

The length `[-0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt]` can be cancelled using `\xpatchcmd` like

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{\\*[0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt]}{\\*[0pt]}{}{}
```

If you want to reduce it drastically, use some negative length like

```
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{\\*[0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt]}{\\*[-10pt]}{}{}
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvlist}{\\*[0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt]}{\\*[0pt]}{}{}



\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{Lebenslauf Heintz Heintz}
  \begin{cvlist}{Schulbildung}
    \item[08/1991--07/2001] Heintz Grundschule Berlin
    \item[08/2001--06/2008] Heintz Schule Berlin \\
     \textit{Abschluss: Abitur (Durchschnittsnote: 2,0)} \\
     \textit{Leistungskurse: Mathematik, Englisch}
  \end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]